# Optimize the parameterization algorithm of a cubic bezier curve

Tags: math, graphics

Except using look-up tables, is there another way to optimize the parameterization algorithm of a cubic Bézier curve like this? (5000 steps for a good parameterization is simply too much for a slower PC, as I need to call this function many times in 1 second):

```
function parameterizeCurve(path, partArc, initialT)
{
   // curve length is already known and globally defined
   // brute force
   var STEPS = 5000; // > precision
   var t = 1 / STEPS;
   var aX=0;
   var aY=0;
   var bX=path[0], bY=path[1];
   var dX=0, dY=0;
   var dS = 0;
   var sumArc = 0;
   var arrT = new Array(Math.round(partArc)); 
   var z = 1;
   arrT[0] = -1;

   var oldpartArc = partArc;
   partArc = partArc - initialT;

   var j = 0;

   for (var i=0; i<STEPS; j = j + t) {
      aX = bezierPoint(j, path[0], path[2], path[4], path[6]);
      aY = bezierPoint(j, path[1], path[3], path[5], path[7]);

      dX = aX - bX;
      dY = aY - bY;
      // deltaS. Pitagora
      dS = Math.sqrt((dX * dX) + (dY * dY));
      sumArc = sumArc + dS;
      if (sumArc >= partArc) {
         arrT[z] = j; // save current t
         z++;
         sumArc = 0;
         partArc = oldpartArc;
      }
      bX = aX;
      bY = aY;
      i++;
   }

   return arrT;
}


    function bezierPoint(t, o1, c1, c2, e1) {
        var C1 = (e1 - (3.0 * c2) + (3.0 * c1) - o1);
        var C2 = ((3.0 * c2) - (6.0 * c1) + (3.0 * o1));
        var C3 = ((3.0 * c1) - (3.0 * o1));
        var C4 = (o1);

        return ((C1*t*t*t) + (C2*t*t) + (C3*t) + C4)
    }
```

Comment: What is the input? What are you optimizing? It looks like you are trying to maximize a distance of some kind..

Comment: Parameterization is a well known matter in math. I need to place equidistant elements on the curve.

Comment: How is the curve defined? Is it a piece-wise 3rd degree bezier curve or something else? I have master's degree in math btw

Comment: Cubic bezier curve with 1 starting 1 ending a 2 control points. path[0] and path[1] are starting point X and starting point Y. path 6 and 7 is the ending point. The others are control points. Please read the comments on the answer below..

Comment: I edited the source code and added the BezierPoint function.

Comment: I've heard that square-roots can be expensive to calculate. Can you work with dS^2 directly? Or use a [fast approximation](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-quakes-fast-inverse-square-root/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've guessed correctly, you're trying to come up with a cubic Bezier curve parameterization that moves at a constant speed along the curve.

So, why do you need 5000 steps? The minimum one can move along a curve is one pixel. A Bezier stays within the convex hull of its four control points, so the length of the curve will be less than that of the polyline `P0 -> P1 -> P2 -> P3`. So find that length in pixels, and use it (instead of 5000).

Let me know if that speeds things up enough.

Comment: I didn't understand but what I'm trying to achieve is to place on the curve some elements which should be equally distant one from the other. I'm doing this very frequently because the curve changes. So I need that the items on the curve are at a very precise place. If I do less than 5000 cycle the whole animation (the items) begin to a little bit dance over the curve because the parameterization is not so precise..and this effect should be avoided and it should be not so expensive.

Comment: Your control points being animated does make this a harder problem. What I was suggesting is adjusting STEPS based on the length of the line joining your control points, instead of fixing its value at 5000.

Comment: What I'm doing there is simply iterating through the t of the curve 5000 times until the end of the curve. Since t's density is not equal on every place (for example on the most curved place the arc between the same t is different then on a more straight place of the curve) I need to iterate through the whole curve. So if I put there the length of the curve instead of 5000 the output numbers are not so precise and I get the items dancing on the curve as the curve changes his control points.

Comment: Hmmm, you could try a "binary search" approach to finding the t. First, try t=1/5000, then try 2*t, see if it exceeds the arc length. If not, double it again, etc. If it exceeds, then go to 1.5*t, etc.

Comment: Great. I got 200-300 steps with certain curve inclinations!

Comment: That's great! I'm very happy to hear that!

Comment: Note, that you can improve length estimation taken the length as length = (length(P0-P1-P2-P3) + length(P0-P3)) / 2. Also you call bezierPoint() twice per point. And again, using de Casteljau algorithm you can do binary search much more efficiently because you will get shorter curve, which is closer to line, after each iteration.